# Intersection between values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

### Problem Statement:

Create new pandas dataframe column showing a boolean of either 1 (intersection) or 0 (no intersection) of row values in two different columns: `row_mods` and `col_mods`.  Another column is added to show what those overlap(s) is (are).  As in the example below, `intersect` takes boolean values, and `common` shows the intersecting value(s).

The rendered pandas dataframe is what I have, the drawn portion is what I'm looking for:

[image]

### Setup:

```
# data
n = np.nan
congruent = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(  
         {'row': ['x','a','b','c','d','e','y'],
            'x': [ n,  5,   5,  5,  5,  5, 5],
            'a': [ 5, n, -.8,-.6,-.3, .8, .01],
            'b': [ 5,-.8,  n, .5, .7,-.9, .01],
            'c': [ 5,-.6, .5,  n, .3, .1, .01],
            'd': [ 5,-.3, .7, .3,  n, .2, .01],
            'e': [ 5, .8,-.9, .1, .2,  n, .01],
            'y': [ 5, .01, .01, .01, .01,  .01, n],
       }).set_index('row')
congruent.columns.names = ['col']
memberships = {'a':['vowel'], 'b':['consonant'], 'c':['consonant'], 'd':['consonant'], 'e':['vowel'], 'y':['consonant', 'vowel'], '*':['wildcard']}

# format stacked df
cs = congruent.stack().to_frame()
cs.columns = ['score']
cs.reset_index(inplace=True)
cs.columns = ['row', 'col', 'score']

# filter col entries not found in membership dict keys
cs['elim'] = (cs['row'].isin(memberships.keys())) & (cs['col'].isin(memberships.keys()))
cs_2 = cs[cs['elim'] == True]

# map col entires to membership dict values
cs_2['row_mods'] = cs_2['row'].map(memberships)
cs_2['col_mods'] = cs_2['col'].map(memberships)
```

How can I perform an intersection across two values in a row across two different columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this mate:

step1, define function:

```
def check_row (row_mods, col_mods):

    common = []

    intersect = 0

    for x in col_mods:

        if x in row_mods:

            intersect = 1
            common.append(x)

    if (intersect == 0):

        common.append(np.nan)

    return (intersect, common)
```

step 2, apply function:

```
cs_2['intersect'] = ''
cs_2['common'] = ''

for index in cs_2.index:

    (intersect, common) = check_row(cs_2.loc[index,'row_mods'], cs_2.loc[index,'col_mods'])

    cs_2.loc[index,'intersect'] = intersect
    cs_2.loc[index,'common'] = [x for x in common]
```

hope it helps! if it does upvote/check answer :)

Comment: This does help.  I wasn't necessarily looking for an iterative method, but vectorized or not, your answer led me to a solution.   The only difference in my implementation is that I used `iterrows` for my row iterator.  Thanks for taking the time to actually read, understand, and answer my question!

Answer (score 2):

Since you're apparently comfortable with the PANDAS operations, I'll supply just the Python intersection logic:

```
common = list(set(row_mods).intersection(set(col_mods)))
intersect = len(common) > 0
```

Briefly, you turn each list of mods into a set, and then use the Python built-in **intersection** method.  Turn the result back into a list.

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: No, sorry.  It doesn't.  Your suggestion would look for an intersection between entire columns. I want to check for intersections across rows for two columns.